# how to get Bitmap from Textureview and pass it to another activity

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, camera, textureview

I have a camera stream on my texture view and also I have a take picture button, Im trying to cast whatever is in the texture view  and send it to another activity.

this is my code:

```
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        _textureView = FindViewById<TextureView>(Resource.Id.textureView);
        _textureView.SurfaceTextureListener = this;
        TakePictureBtn = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.takePhotoButton);
        TakePictureBtn.Click += TakePicture_Click;

    }

    private void TakePicture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Bitmap Photo;
        Photo = _textureView.GetBitmap(640,480);
        Intent PictureActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(PictureActivity));
        PictureActivity.PutExtra("Photo", Photo);
        this.StartActivity(PictureActivity);
    }
```

ans this is the other activity code:

```
 public class PictureActivity : Activity
    {
        ImageView Photo;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.PictureActivity);
            Photo = FindViewById<ImageView>(Resource.Id.imageView1);
            Photo.SetImageBitmap((Bitmap)Intent.GetParcelableExtra("Photo"));
            // Create your application here
        }
    }
```

but when I press the button nothing happens, is this the correct way to do this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your click event  you should

```
 private void TakePicture_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _camera.TakePicture(null, null, this);         
        }
```

then add:

```
public void OnPictureTaken(byte[] data, Android.Hardware.Camera camera)
        {
            _camera.StopPreview();
            Bitmap picture = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(data, 0, data.Length);
            Intent PictureActivity = new Intent(this, typeof(PictureActivity));
            PictureActivity.PutExtra("Photo", picture);
            this.StartActivity(PictureActivity);
            _camera.StartPreview();
        }
```

do not forget to:

```
 public class Activity1 : Activity, TextureView.ISurfaceTextureListener, IPictureCallback
```